# Unable to import required dependencies: dateutil: No module named 'dateutil'

Tags: python

I have looked through some other posts but nothing I found had my error. I have tried installing dateutil, but it keeps saying requirements already satisfied. Here is the entire error:

```
File "C:/Course/AiCourse/AI-K-nearest.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Course\AiCourse\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
dateutil: No module named 'dateutil'
```

I am using pycharm

Edit: **It seems to be an issue with the pandas module because when I uninstall it, the problem doesn't occur, but of course I do need this module.**

Comment: are you installing it for the correct version of python? Maybe you install it on  python version x and run your code on version y

Comment: first try `import dateutil` in python, if that does not work do: `pip install datetime`

Comment: @snatchysquid sorry im kind of new, how can you check. I know my python is version 3.7

Comment: @KetZoomer It did download something, but it still gives the error

Comment: checking versions with pip can be done with `pip --version`, besides the pip version it should also mention the python version.

Comment: @snatchysquid I do run my code on the same version

Comment: When i run pip install python-dateutil it says `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-datutil (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-datutil`

Comment: try: `sudo apt-get install python3-dateutil`

Comment: @KetZoomer It looks like OP is using Windows (note the C: in the filepath in the stack trace). So using the `apt` package manager wouldn't work.

Comment: whoops sorry, forgot he was on windows for a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So I finally got it to work. It seemed like a glitch, but if anyone else is wondering how I fixed it, it was pretty simple.**

1. I opened up file explorer and looked for the file in the directory it said.
2. I didn't find it so I did a search.
3. The file showed up and when I tried to delete it it gave an error and said the file
   was moved and it couldn't be deleted.
4. When I went back to Pycharm I had to redownload dateutil.

Then everything worked fine.